# Gradle script: Classcast Exception in ant.copy task

Tags: gradle, groovy, ant

I have a Gradle script in which I need to copy a bunch of files from srcPath to tgtPath while specifying include and exclude patterns.

Normaly I would do this with Gradle's built-in copy task but here I also need to convert the character encoding while doing so. I thus am trying to use the ant.copy method because it supports "encoding" and "outputEncoding" arguments, which are supposed to support exactly such conversions.

So I defined me a method as follows:

```
private void copy(String srcPath, String tgtPath, includePatterns = ['**/*'], excludePatterns = []) {
    println "copying from '${srcPath}' to '${tgtPath}' (incl:'${includePatterns}' / excl:'${excludePatterns}'):"

    new AntBuilder().copy(todir: tgtPath, 
                          encoding: StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1, 
                          outputEncoding: StandardCharsets.UTF_8) {
        fileset(dir: srcPath, 
                includes: includePatterns, 
                excludes: excludePatterns)
    }
}
```

When I execute this as part of my Gradle build (actually within a .groovy file which is why I am using "new AntBuilder.copy(...)" here instead of just "ant.copy(...)" I get the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration

??? What has this to do with XML-parsing? I don't understand at all why I am getting this error.
I only found a couple of examples but no real documentation on how to use this method from Groovy. Ant's documentation claims that "includes" and "excludes" accepts lists of arguments which is what I am passing here. Any idea, what am I doing wrong here or why this doesn't work?

Or any other suggestion on how to convert character encodings while copying files over in Gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use Gradle's [built in ant integration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html).

Eg:

```
project.ant.copy(todir: tgtPath, 
                          encoding: StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1, 
                          outputEncoding: StandardCharsets.UTF_8) {
        fileset(dir: srcPath, 
                includes: includePatterns, 
                excludes: excludePatterns)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! A shame I hadn't thought about that myself <blush>. I had falsely assumed that "new AntBuilder()" and "project.ant" are equivalent, but obviously not so. Thanks again!